# 'object' Does not contain for 'value'

Tags: c#

I'm building a function to reduce the same code of 18 buttons.

Here is the code:

```
void hexagon_Click(object sender, ActionEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            sender.RectOne.Fill = sender.Brush;
            sender.RectTwo.Fill = sender.Brush;
            sender.RectThree.Fill = sender.Brush;
        }));
        if (count == 1)
        {
            kliknatopole = sender;
        }
        else if (count == 2)
        {
            if (kliknatopole == sender)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                if (kliknatopole.Brush == sender.brush)
                {
                    levelUpControUI(level);
                    prepareForNextLevel();
                    nextLevel1();
                    count = 0;
                    sender.Enabled = false;
                    kliknatopole.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        sender.RectOne.Fill = sender.Brush;
                        sender.RectTwo.Fill = sender.Brush;
                        sender.RectThree.Fill = sender.Brush;
                    }));
                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
                    {
                        sender.RectOne.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                        sender.RectTwo.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                        sender.RectThree.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                        kliknatopole.RectOne.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                        kliknatopole.RectTwo.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                        kliknatopole.RectThree.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
                    }));
                    toLevelOne();
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now i don't know why, but `kliknatopole` which is a `private object` and `sender` can't access the values from the class `HexagonControl`, here it is:

```
 public partial class HexagonControl : UserControl
{
    public BaseControlLogic controlLogic { get; set; }
    public HexagonControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        controlLogic = new BaseControlLogic();
    }

    public Rectangle RectOne { get { return rectOne; } }
    public Rectangle RectTwo { get { return rectTwo; } }
    public Rectangle RectThree { get { return rectThree; } }
    public Brush Brush { set; get; }
}
```

For `RectOne,Two and Three` , and also `Brush`, i get this error:

`'object' does not contain a definition for 'RectOne' and no extension method 'RectOne' accepting a first argument of of type 'object' could be found`

I put `HexagonControl` as public, but that didnt fix it. I also tried creating an `object` and passing the `sender` value in, but that still didnt fix it, it just gave me this `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'LongName.HexagonControl'. An explicit conversion exists`

What could be causing this error, and how can i fix it.

Comment: You have to cast `sender` to its original type

Comment: @FlatEric this should be an answer rather than a comment

Comment: In my case how can that be done. I'm new to c#, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast `sender` to `HexagonControl` type or send it's value to another `HexaControl` type variable. Try the following:

```
void hexagon_Click(object sender, ActionEventArgs e)
{
    if(sender.GetType() != typeof(HexagonControl))
            return;
    count++;
    HexagonControl realSender = (HexagonControl) sender;

    [...]
```

And use `realSender` instead of `sender` in the rest of the method. This way you prevent an `Exception` in case `sender` is not an `HexagonControl`, just for precaution.

Hope it helps!

Comment: The sender part gets fixed, but now i get this: Operator ! cannot be applied to opperand of type 'System.Type'

Comment: @Xy. Try changing the if line for this: `if(sender.GetType() != typeof(HexagonControl))`, I made a mistake, already edited the answer, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

Just cast `sender` to its original type:

```
((HexagonControl)sender).RectOne.Fill = ((HexagonControl)sender).Brush;
```

Of course you have to do this for the other 8 usages as well

Comment: @Xy have you done this for *all* cases where you use `sender`?

Comment: Have you done it for `kliknatopole` as well, since it also is a reference to `sender` and is also of type `object`?

Comment: Yes i did, and it still gave me the same error. I found the solution, thank you for your time